# CSS refuse to obey

Tags: html, css

I'll make this short, I got this webpage :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <ul id="navList">
            <li><a href="#" id="navActive">foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bar</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With this CSS 
style.css

```
body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#000000;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

nav.css

```
#navList
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-image:url('../img/menu.png');
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:12px 150px;
}

#navList li
{
    display:inline;
}

#navList li a
{
    color:#bfbfbf;
    padding:14px 25px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#navList li a:hover
{
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#bfbfbf;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#navActive
{
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#bfbfbf;
}
```

It looks like the CSS from the navActive id is never being applied... Could someone tell me why and/or suggest me a way to correct this.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks o.k. to me. Do you happen to have a live example? A quick look with Firebug usually solves things like this.

Comment: Can you try using `#navList li a#navActive` instead of `#navActive` as the selector? I think using an ID *should* always have precedence but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the selector

```
#navList li a
```

is more heavily weighted than

```
#navActive
```

as it is more specific.

You can overcome it by adding

```
color:#000000 !important;
```

or using

```
#navList li a#navActive
```

as the selector

Comment: I thought that an ID selector has the highest specificity, is this not correct?

Comment: Alex is correct. The scores are added together, so an id with 2 tags is more specific than an id by itself.

Comment: Is the "!important" tag compatible with every browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#navActive
{
    color:#000000 !important;
    background-color:#bfbfbf;
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EJGGQ/).  It's a specificity fight, in this case the original `#navList li a` is winning.  Another alternative is using `#navList li a#navActive` without the `!important`.